# Any multi threaded curl library for PHP that supports dynamic instance addition?

Tags: php, class, curl

Previously I have used a multi curl library for PHP that facilitates fetching multiple pages in parallel (basically an easy to use API), but it was lacking one feature. You would pass a callback function to the class instance to be called after each stream completes, but it couldn't add another URL to that multi curl class to continue the process. 
Let's take an example: I provide 20 basic URLs to the multi curl class and specify it to use no more than 10 threads at the same time, the rest 10 are in queue. Once one thread is completed, the callback function is called with the fetched page as argument. This all I have. What I would like to do is in the callback function, based on the fetched page contents (contains a string) to add another URL with it's own curl options to that same queue. If it's not clear still please let me know, I will try to clarify. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a note to above, I'm looking for a class that would do this, lately I've found several multi curl classes that support a queue and a callback function, but none of them could work with that queue (add new instances) after the class instance was given the comand to run (curl_multi_exec)

Answer (score 1):

The multi interface in libcurl (the library providing the actual functionality to the PHP/CURL binding) fully supports new transfers to get added (and existing to be removed) during run-time.

If the PHP binding truly doesn't support this, then I figure it should be fairly easy to modify it to so as this is not an actual limitation of libcurl.